# Building quick sort and merge sort

Tags: c++, arrays, merge, quicksort, mergesort

I have built functions related to quick sort and merge sort. I am not getting any errors but still I am not getting the required output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b);

void printarray(int array[], int size);

int partition(int array[], int low, int high, int select);

void quicksort(int array[], int low, int high, int select);

void merge(int arr[], int p, int q, int r);

void mergesort(int arr[], int l, int r);

int main() {
    int n, arr[20], selection, num, select;
    int divide = 0, merge_count = 0;
    cout << "Enter the total number of elements:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the elements:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    cout << "Which method would you like to choose?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Quick sort" << endl << "2. Merge Sort" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        cout << "Which element would you choose to be the pivot element?" << endl;
        cout << "1. First element" << endl << "2. Middle element" << endl << "3. Last element" << endl;
        cin >> selection;
        switch (selection) {
          case 1:
            select = 0;
            cout << "pivot element = " << arr[select] << endl;
            quicksort(arr, 0, n - 1, select);
            printarray(arr, n);
            break;
          case 2:
            select = n / 2;
            cout << "pivot element = " << arr[select] << endl;
            quicksort(arr, 0, n - 1, select);
            printarray(arr, n);
            break;
          case 3:
            select = n - 1;
            cout << "pivot element = " << arr[select] << endl;
            quicksort(arr, 0, n - 1, select);
            printarray(arr, n);
            break;
          default:
            cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        mergesort(arr, 0, n - 1);
        printarray(arr, n);
        break;
      default:
        cout << "invalid input" << endl;
        break;
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void printarray(int array[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int partition(int array[], int low, int high, int select) {
    
    int pivot = array[select];
    
    int i = (low - 1);
    
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
        }
    }
    
    swap(&array[i + 1], &array[high]);
    
    return (i + 1);
}

void quicksort(int array[], int low, int high, int select) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pi = partition(array, low, high, select);
        
        quicksort(array, low, pi - 1, select);
        
        quicksort(array, pi + 1, high, select);
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    
    int L[n1], M[n2];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[p + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        M[j] = arr[q + 1 + j];
    
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = p;
    
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= M[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = M[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = M[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergesort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        
        mergesort(arr, l, m);
        mergesort(arr, m + 1, r);
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

At first my quicksort was working just fine, but then I added the code for mergesort(I did not edit the code for quicksort at all) and now none of them are working as expected.

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the total number of elements:
6
Enter the elements:
12
14
15
13
11
10
Which method would you like to choose?
1. Quick sort
2. Merge Sort
1
Which element would you choose to be the pivot element?
1. First element
2. Middle element
3. Last element
1
pivot element = 12
12 11 10 15 13 14
```

Comment: Simplify your testing: Use an array initialized with hard-coded values. That will remove al the complexity of the input handling. It will also make it easier to *debug* your program which is something you should take this as the perfect opportunity to learn. Use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, and you will probably notice when things starts to go wrong very quickly.

Comment: I guess your code is crashing, using a debugger will show you where

Comment: This is not how it works. You can't modify one of separated and independent parts of code and break the other one. So your `quicksort` has got some mistake (I'll test it and maybe will post an anwser).

Comment: Looks like the error in `partition` function: just use [debug with rubber duck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281270/what-does-rubber-duck-mean-in-debug-help)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `quicksort` is flawed: you select an element as the pivot from a fixed offset `select` from each slice of the array. When you recurse on the partitions, `select` should be recomputed from the slice length to refer to an element of the slice. As coded, your program has undefined behavior: the flaw in quicksort corrupts memory outside the array being sorted, potentially causing other functions to fail as well.

Furthermore, your implementation of `mergesort` is flawed as well: you do not increment `k` in the main `while` loop of the `merge` function, producing invalid output that might, by chance, go unnoticed in very specific cases. You should run a check before printing the sorted array.